# Explicit template instantiation and debug load time

Tags: c++, gdb, explicit-instantiation, debug-information

I have been wondering if the use of explicit template instantiation can help reduce the time that it takes the debugger to load binaries. Something similar to [reducing link time](https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-572) by the same mechanisms.

In the same vein, are there any ways to measure this? I can use `readelf -e` to see the size of the debuginfo, like

```
 [33] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  048d175c
       000000000583f7f3  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

Is there anything finer grained (without having all of the gory details)?

For info, this is with GCC and GDB on Linux (RHEL 6.6).

Answer (score 0):

> Something similar to reducing link time by the same mechanisms.

It most likely will not work.

The mechanism used to speed up the build via explicit instantiation: instead of emitting automatic template method(s) into every `.o` which needs them, and then having the linker discard duplicates, it explicitly instantiate the method(s) into a single file (resulting in smaller `.o` files and less work for the linker).

But for debug info, the debugger is *not* looking at the `.o` files; it looks at the resulting linked executable or shared library. And by the time the link is done, the linker *has already discarded* all (or most) of the duplicates.

So you will probably not observe any speedup from explicit instantiation.

(It may not be possible to discard *all* duplicate debug info, so you may in fact find a tiny speedup, but I doubt it will be anywhere near 40% improvement.)